# Why is the parameter variable empty?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl controller class in which I do:

```
sub func1 {
    my $f1    = Model::myModel->new();
    my $param = "test";
    $f1->func2($param);
}
```

Model class:

```
sub new {
    my ($class, %arg) = @_;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub func2 {
    my ($self, $param) = shift(@_);
    warn $param;
}
```

`$param` is blank. What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Updated with additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shift` only shifts the first value off of `@_`.  `perldoc -f shift` will tell you more about how shift works.

You want:

```
my( $self, $param ) = @_;
```

<strike>You had it right in `new()`.  Not sure what happened ;)</strike>

Actually, FYI, your `new()` will give the warning:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment
```

If you call it like `$package->new( 'a' );`  You might want to trap that, something like:

```
use Carp qw( croak confess );
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    confess "$class requires an even number of args" if( @_ & 1 );
    my %args = @_;
    # ...
}
```

Or using whatever exception catching mechanism you use.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sub func2 {
  my ( $self, $param ) = @_;
  warn $param;
}
```

or

```
sub func2 {
  my $self  = shift @_;
  my $param = shift @_;
  warn $param;
}
```